# Can there be ever a counterexample to this?

Tags: vector-spaces

Does addition on subspaces have an additive identity?

I said yes because subspaces are vector spaces, so they must have an additive identity.

Which subspaces have additive inverses?

I said all of them, because they are vector spaces. (even $\{0\}$ have additive inverses, right?)

Is there some weird counterexample to this trough? I missed something?

Comment: Nope, doesn't seem like you missed anything.  Linear subspaces are, by definition, subsets of a vector space that also have a vector space structure.

Comment: And yes, $\{0\}$ is a perfectly good vector space.  $0+0=0$, so every element in $\{0\}$ (i.e. only $0$) has an additive inverse.

Comment: Yes, a *subset* of a vector space is a *subspace* if itself is a vector space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Comments turned answer:)

Given a $\mathbb{F}$-vector space $V$, a linear subspace $W$ is, *by definition*, a subset $W\subset V$ such that

1. $0\in W$,
2. for each $v,w\in W$ we have $v+w\in W$, and
3. for each $v\in W$ and $\lambda\in \mathbb{F}$, $\lambda v\in W$.

This makes $W$ into a $\mathbb{F}$-vector space as well.  It is not hard to see that

- It has an operation $+:W\times W\rightarrow W$ called vector addition, given by restricting $+$ from $V$ to $W$, which by 2. above is well-defined.
- It has an additive identity, $0$, which follows from 1.
- $+$ is associative and commutative (it is the restriction of an associative and commutative operation, and hence has these properties as well)
- It has an operation $\cdot: \mathbb{F}\times W \rightarrow W$ called scalar multiplication, given by restricting $\cdot$ from $V$ to $W$, which by 3. above is well-defined.
- $\cdot$ is compatible with the field multiplication and with the multiplicative identity of $\mathbb{F}$, since it is the restriction of an operation that has the same properties.
- $\cdot$ distributes over vector addition and over field addition, again because it is the restriction of an operation that has the same properties.
- Finally, for every $v\in W$ we have an element $-v\in W$ such that $v+(-v)=0$.  This is because $-v=(-1)\cdot v\in W$ by the above properties that $W$ satisfies.